# Threads writing each their own file is slower than writing all files sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading

I am learning about threading in Python, and wrote a short test program which creates 10 csv-files and writes 100k lines in each of the files. I assumed it would be faster to let 10 threads write each their own file, but for some reason it is 2x slower than simply writing all files in sequence.

I think this might have to do with the way the threading is treated by the OS, but not sure. I am running this on Linux.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light on why this is the case.

Multi-thread version:

```
import thread, csv


N = 10  #number of threads

exitmutexes = [False]*N

def filewriter(id_):
    with open('files/'+str(id_)+'.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for i in xrange(100000):
            writer.writerow(["efweef", "wefwef", "666w6efw", "6555555"])
    exitmutexes[id_] = True

for i in range(N):
    thread.start_new_thread(filewriter, (i,))

while False in exitmutexes: #checks whether all threads are done
    pass
```

Note: I have tried to include a sleep in the while-loop so that main thread is free at intervals, but this had no substantial effect.

Regular version:

```
import time, csv


for i in range(10):
    with open('files2/'+str(i)+'.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for i in xrange(100000):
            writer.writerow(["efweef", "wefwef", "666w6efw", "6555555"])
```

Comment: Not so familiar with python, but it seems the main thread might consume an entire cpu core. That loop does not seem to ever rest or check time, so looks like it will just burn cpu while waiting. Does python somehow prevent that?

Comment: @joshp Yes, that is a good point. I forgot to mention that I tried to include a sleep there to free up the main thread.

Comment: Look up Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: Sequential writes are often much faster on traditional spinning disk hard drives because of the nature of the read-write head (linked answer relates to C, but the same concept applies) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421767/multithread-read-from-disk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. Due to Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), Python will not use more than one CPU core at a time for the data generation part, so your data generation won't be sped up by running multiple threads. You'll need multi processing to improve CPU bound operation.
2. But that's not really the core of the problem here, because the GIL is released when you do I/O like writing to disk. The core of the problem is that you're writing to ten different places at a time, which most likely causes the harddisk head to thrash around as the hard disk head switches around between ten different places in the disk. Serial writes is almost always fastest in a hard disk.
3. Even if you have CPU bound operation and use multiprocessing, using ten thread won't give you any significant advantage in data generation unless you actually have ten CPU cores. If you use more threads than the number of CPU cores, you'll pay the cost of thread switching, but you'll never speed up the total runtime of a CPU bound operation.

If you use more threads than available CPU, the total run time always increases or at most stay the same. The only reason to use more threads than CPU cores is if you are consuming the result of the threads interactively or in a pipeline with other systems. There are edge cases where you can speed up a poorly designed, I/O bound program by using threads. But a well designed single thread program will most likely perform just as well or better.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the dreaded GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)

"*In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe. (However, since the GIL exists, other features have grown to depend on the guarantees that it enforces.)*"

This essentially means each python interpreter (and thus script) is locked to one logical core on your machine, and no two threads will be executed simultaneously, unless you decide to spawn to separate processes.

Consult this page for more details:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: The GIL is released when writing to a file. This is unlikely to be the actual cause of this particular problem, unless you have significant CPU bound computation.